# Determining the set of valid next terminals when generating from a CFG

Tags: parsing, grammar, bnf, formal-languages

I am trying to generate random sentences from a context-free grammar. During each step, the next non-terminal to be generated is determined according to some probabilistic criteria irrelevant to this question. Where I am stuck is, given a grammar and the partial sentence generated so far, how do I determine the set of non-terminals that can be generated at the next step according to the grammar?

Below is an example grammar in BNF and a partial generation.

```
<expr> ::= <term> "+" <expr> | <term>
<term> ::= <term> "*" <factor> | <factor>
<factor> ::= "(" <expr> ")" | <const>
<const> ::= "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4"
```

Supposed generated sequence so far: `( 1 +`. In this case, we can easily see that the next token to be generated should come from the set `{"(", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4"}`.

Is there an algorithm to determine this set given a general grammar and a partial generation, or generate the sentence in a way that makes this set available at each step?

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach to generating sentences is to start with the start symbol and then repeatedly substitute the first (or last) non-terminal with one of its productions, using a sampling criterion not entirely relevant to this answer.

If the grammar is left-to-right parseable, you could simply parse the prefix and then select one of the terminals for which  a non-error action exists. That requires the parse tables for whatever left-to-right algorithm is applicable. If the algorithm is LALR(k), you need to watch out for reduce actions which lead to eventual errors. To avoid that scenario, if you decide to choose a reduce action, do not commit to the corresponding lookahead symbol. Only commit when you do a shift. (But you cannot ignore the lookaheads corresponding to the reduce action either; you need to keep the entire set so that you can ensure that the lookahead symbol is chosen consistently.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case, I do not have the option of choosing a production to substitute the last non-terminal with. Rather, I have a vocabulary of all the terminals to choose from and at each step of generation I want to limit the choices to legal terminals depending on the prefix. Can I get away with not parsing the prefix and generate the sentence directly in a way compatible with the way I determine the next token?